# Python cv2.imread doesn't work

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to read an image file but it returns an all-zero matrix.

```
import cv2

a = cv2.imread('0000.jpg')
print(a)
```

Even a.shape works well, print(a) prints only 0 values.
I need your help

Comment: Try `a.sum()` and see what it prints...

Comment: Try with `cv::imshow()` to debug the image.

Comment: Thank you. The image have empty spaces on the 4 corners. I solved the problem.